# How to avoid temp file when using jinja2 in ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-template

I want to do quite a basic thing in ansible which is:

- Generate a file using a jinja2 template with an extra-var passed to my playbook
- Use the generated file as a parameter of a command line
  But I'd like to avoid to create any temporary file. See below a sample with the creation of a temporary file (Sample 1) and one without a temporary file (Sample 2).

My question is:
Is there a nicer way (shortest way e.g one task only) to write a playbook along the lines of Sample 2 without using a temporary file ?

Thx in advance.

## Sample 1: Using a temporary file

Here is an example of the many tries I made:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  any_errors_fatal: true

  ################################################################
  # Mandatory --extra-vars                                       #
  #     myvar    : My variable                                   #
  # ##############################################################
  vars:
    myvar: "{{ myvar }}"

  tasks:

        - name: Create temporary file
          tempfile:
            state: file
            prefix: ansible
            suffix: mysuffix
          register: my_temp_file

        - name: Generate file from template replacing my_var by its value in dest file
          template:
            src: ./templates/mytemplate.j2
            dest: "{{ my_temp_file.path }}"

        - name: use file generated with jinja2
          shell: |
            cat "{{ my_temp_file.path }}" | ./mycommand -f -

        - name: Use the registered var and the file module to remove the temporary file
          file:
            path: "{{ my_temp_file.path }}"
            state: absent
          when: my_temp_file.path is defined
```

## Sample 2: without temporary file

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  any_errors_fatal: true

  ################################################################
  # Mandatory --extra-vars                                       #
  #     myvar    : My variable                                   #
  # ##############################################################
  vars:
    myvar: "{{ myvar }}"

  tasks:
    - name: get output of templating engine when applied on template
      set_fact:
        rendered_template: "{{ lookup('template', './templates/mytemplate.j2') }}"

    - name: use file generated with jinja2
      shell: |
        cat <<< "{{ rendered_template }}" | ./mycommand -f -
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [stdin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/command_module.html#parameter-stdin), e.g.

```yaml
- name: Use stdin generated by Jinja2
  command:
    cmd: ./mycommand -f -
    stdin: "{{ lookup('template', 'templates/mytemplate.j2') }}"
```

Then you can also use [command](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/command_module.html#ansible-builtin-command-execute-commands-on-targets) instead of [shell](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/shell_module.html#ansible-builtin-shell-execute-shell-commands-on-targets). Quoting from [Notes](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/shell_module.html#notes):

> *"If you want to execute a command securely and predictably, it may be better to use the ansible.builtin.command module instead."*